# Spark-OTF font is not found

Tags: fonts, compilation-error

I want to produce sparklines with `spark-otf` and this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{spark-otf}

\begin{document}
\sparkBar{0,4,3,52,4,2,3}
\end{document}
```

But I get this error message:

```
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "Sparks Bar Medium" not found.
! Font \sparkBarMedium=name:Sparks Bar Medium:mode=node;+calt; not loadable: me
tric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
\font 
l.59   \font
          \sparkBarNarrow     = "name:Sparks Bar Narrow:mode=node;+calt;\spa...
```

However checking the installation of my TeXLive says, that `spark-otf` is installed:

```
package:     spark-otf
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Support OpenType Spark fonts
longdesc:    The package supports the free fonts from "After the Flood" which are available from AtF Spark. The following fonts are supported: Spark -- Bar -- Medium Spark -- Bar -- Narrow Spark -- Bar -- Thin Spark -- Dot-line -- Medium Spark -- Dot -- Medium Spark -- Dot -- Small
installed:   Yes
revision:    51005
sizes:       doc: 133k, run: 9k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 0.05
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  font-absent font-symbol font-otf font-use
collection:  collection-latexextra
```

Any suggestions what I did wrong?

Comment: the description you quote inplies you need to install the fonts separately  "....which are available from AtF Spark"

Comment: From the manual (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spark-otf): `The fonts are available from https://github.com/aftertheflood/spark and should be saved either
in Library/fonts/ (MAC OSX), c:\Windows\Fonts (Windows) or /usr/local/share/fonts (Linux) or
any other location where the fonts will be found by the system.`

Comment: Thanks for this. I was mistaking "support" with "provide". Nevertheless the font is not available anymore under the link from the package documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments. The package `spark-otf` only provides the support for the spark-font, not the font files themselves.

You need to download the font files and install them.

The files are available from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/aftertheflood/sparks/releases/download/v2.0/Sparks-font-complete.zip).